# Are numpy/pandas vectorized calculations faster with MKL or with the bottleneck library?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy, intel-mkl

Currently I use [bottleneck](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Bottleneck) to improve performance of a huge (100K lines) vectorized numpy/pandas code. This has resulted in a significant gain. Now I'm considering to use MKL for BLAS instead of the current BLAS library, but I'm not an expert and I am afraid I'll just lose what I already gained on my setup.

Would I lose the performance I gained with bottleneck to get the speedup of MKL? Can I combine the two approaches?

Comment: Compile *what* with MKL? What are you currently using that MKL would replace? Even with this information, there's probably not much to say other than you'll have to try it and see if you get any speedups.

Comment: @bnaecker Updated text, thanks!

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. If you already used numpy, depending on the operations you either used some BLAS-implementation or you did not. In the former case: how can that be slowed down by some (assumption:) faster BLAS? In the latter: no change. Also: the intersection of bottleneck's function and BLAS-ops is ~ 0 (of course those functions might use BLAS internally). Without knowing what you really want to change it's hard to foresee any consequences.

Comment: @sascha I am already using BLAS, but not the MKL version. But this is exactly what I wanted to know: "the intersection of bottleneck's function and BLAS-ops is ~ 0 (of course those functions might use BLAS internally)". I'd be glad to accept this as an answer (assuming the question makes more sense now).

Comment: Well i have to admit i maybe simplified too much in regards to this. It's hard to understand the question and to put thoughts into short text: BLAS -> MKL should not slow things down. BLAS -> MKL could speed up things if BLAS is used anywhere in your code; within bottleneck or not. This assumes MKL in general faster than your BLAS. Of course there are more complex middle-cases: is there some function, where a non-bottleneck BLAS is slower than bottleneck, but where MKL would be even faster. And that's something hard to answer without checking out bottlenecks functions and implementations.